# Will Odin 6 be updateable?

Tags: updates

I have a box I use for pro linux audio only. For work, I use arch linux, but for the audio box, I want and need a stable system where I can focus on the audio and not the system, and also doesn't threaten my stability due to frequent updates.

That's why, some years ago, I installed elementary os 5.1 there. Beautiful, fast, easy and gets out of the way for the tasks I run that box for. I was always happy with it.

Until I recently bought a linux-supported audio software from u-he which only runs with glibc 2.28. While 5.1 runs with 2.27 only. And there is no upgrade path, not for those libs, nor the OS itself (e.g. from 5.1 to 6).

Now I have to reluctantly update the whole system. This is huge. I'll need to backup everything (which I do regularly but still, you know what this implies), and re-install a new OS from scratch.

I am of course considering elementary OS 6 again. However, I would like to avoid this same issue.

Will there be an upgrade path from 6. to 6.x and eventually 7 or whatever comes after? This will be important for me to take the right decision here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not. The authors of elementary os have the fear, that the update will eventuelly break the system and the user then say it is the fault of elementary and not debian. You will to have reinstall it again.

By the way, why not try fedora for audio? It has pipewire as default audio system activated, thats a huge advantage, as debian / ubuntu / elementary use alsa / pulseaudio. Pipewire runs really smooth, you can do many things (like routing your streams) and it has a much lower latency.

Comment: I have never used fedora. I have used pretty much every distro around, but I don't know why I never tried fedora. Possibly I had always had the perception it to be rather enterprise oriented. Maybe time to give it a try. Thanks.